# Delete youtube comment fails

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Why does the delete function of the youtube API fail for comments

Scopes on authentication: `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"`

Curl Request

```bash
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?
id=COMMENT_ID&key=ACCOUNT_KEY' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

Error:

```json
{
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid.",
            "domain": "youtube.comment",
            "reason": "processingFailure",
            "location": "id",
            "locationType": "parameter"
        }
    ]
}
}
```